# How do I set a formula in a cell using R1C1 notation from variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a series of IF/ELSE clauses to see if items fit into one of three categories. If an item doesn't fit into any of them, its category field should simply read "SELECT".

Now, with simple text strings it works fine. But I also want to include a simple formula (as in most of the other autopopulated fields in the sheet) to blank the field if it's on an empty line. Based on the code I've used in other cases, I would want to set the cell's formula to

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A2, "", "SELECT")
```

(...where the cell itself is B2)

Problem is, the cell to look at will depend on which line it's on; A2, A3, A4 and so on. The column number remains constant, but the row number is defined by the variable `iImportCounter`.

I've tried both `.Value` and `.Formula`, both `"""` and `Chr(34)`, and it still doesn't seem to work. The full code for that line as it stands is

```
Else:
    wsCalc.Cells(iImportCounter, 3).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($" & Application.ConvertFormula(Cells(iImportCounter, 2), xlA1) & ", " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "SELECT" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Is there something terribly obvious I'm missing?

I've seen comments elsewhere that the fact that it's in a module rather than a sheet-based macro could make some of that code malfunction, but I'm not sure what or how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `wsCalc` is a reference to a range of cells:

```
wscalc.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC1),"""",""SELECT"")"
```

As a working example:

```
Sub Test()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC1),"""",""SELECT"")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the `iImportCounter` starts at. If it is **3** (*row 3* in B3) then the formula would be,

```
with wsCalc.Cells(iImportCounter, 3)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(R[-1]C1), """", ""SELECT"")
end with
```

The **R** in **RC1** means the same row that you are putting the formula on so if you are putting on row 2 and you want to reference A2 then **R** is all you need. If the formula is going into B3 then you need to reference the current row minus 1 with **R[-1]C1**.

The **C1** in **RC1** means a 'locked' (*absolute*) column A (the *first* column). This doesn't seem absolutely necessary as the formula does not travel laterally.

Comment: Ah, good catch - sorry, it would be all in the same row and the formula would (in this example) be going in B2. Fixed now, thanks. And the code there works nicely, too.